# Unable to install vim plugins

Tags: vim, vi, nixos, nix, nixpkgs

I am unable to install any vim plugins on nixOS

running the command:

```
nix-env -i vimplugin-Syntastic
```

gives these as the last 3 lines of output:

```
output path ‘/nix/store/3bcdjr4hwgrimcimdg2115prpfm83xca-syntastic-4782184’ should 
have r:sha256 hash ‘1vjh3a3w6whvaws86z48j8bp7dgavvix8a2kgjn195axs83hpkxy’, instead has 
‘01a1px7i77ajc4y8czwhkhhqif89q6yf26wpjakh3asdv7cvnidm’

cannot build derivation ‘/nix/store/478msfr0bm6h64zp0ri5c98dgkp4zrcd-vimplugin-
Syntastic-2015-02-17.drv’: 1 dependencies couldn't be built

error: build of ‘/nix/store/478msfr0bm6h64zp0ri5c98dgkp4zrcd-vimplugin-Syntastic-2015-02-17.drv’ failed
```

All the other output appears normal until these last lines.
I'm having the exact same problem with other vim plugins, i've tried 4 other plugins:

```
Solarized
Nerd commenter
airline
ctrp
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm, we had a wrong hash specified in the expression, it seems. I pushed a fix to master https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/commit/f799749 EDIT: actually the following 46b48b0b4 commit resolved the bad plugins (probably all their hashes were broken).